# goto keyword in java

Tags: java, keyword

Why is the `goto` keyword in java reserved though it is not used?

**EDIT :** Just to rephrase the question once again to avoid the ambiguity, I understand goto functionality is not supported in java and also understand that it makes code difficult to read. But its not supported, so then why make it reserved. It can be used as variable names atleast