# Java label statement and goto

Tags: java, label, goto

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [goto keyword in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334376/goto-keyword-in-java)

1. There is no goto in java, right ?
2. Why goto is still considered a keyword then ?
3. Label syntax (only properly* used before a loop/if statement ?? ) and called through (label, break label, continue label)

*properly cause when i used before `x=3` it couldn't be read after it are there any other cases ?

```
            int x = 2;
        label: x = 3;
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            System.out.println(j);
        }
        label;  // Compile error (no local variable label)
```

Comment: similar (possible duplicate) questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334376/goto-keyword-in-java and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430782/alternative-to-goto-statement-in-java

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [section 3.9 of the JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#229308):

> The keywords `const` and `goto` are reserved, even though they are not currently used. This may allow a Java compiler to produce better error messages if these C++ keywords incorrectly appear in programs.

Answer (score 3):

> There is no goto in java, right ?

Yes

> Why goto is still considered a keyword then ?

Yes it is considered by standards, [for official doc please see details link given by Jon]

For Labels : See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821827/loop-in-java-code-what-is-this-why-does-it-compile-and-generally-wtf/3821841#3821841)

Answer (score 1):

1 - There is no goto in Java (the language), there is goto in Java  (the virtual machine)
2 - The keywords const and goto are reserved, even though they are not currently used. This may allow a Java compiler to produce better error messages if these C++ keywords incorrectly appear in programs. (from [The java language specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#3.9))
3 - what is the question?

Anyway, read the The java language specification several times before going to SCJP (isn't OCJP now? )

Comment: yeah it's ocjp, I just used to call it scjp :), will edit it