# Is goto and cont keywords in java

Tags: java

*If goto and const keywords are not used in java then why java list them in the java keyword list.*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334376/goto-keyword-in-java?rq=1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7428358/why-const-keyword-is-not-used-in-java

Comment: http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goto

Comment: @mcalex What's your point?

Comment: I think you mean `const`

Answer (score 1):

They are reserved for future use, only not *yet* in use. They might have use in a future version of Java.