# Spring, Jsp , goto variable

Tags: spring, jsp, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, jspx

Today I was just coding some Jspx page using Spring framework and an error appared that I didn't understand because I had just copy past the same several time and it was working perfectly with just the original line. It seems that the following lines were unusable :

```
<spring:url var="goto" value="/resources/images/goto16.png" />

<img alt="goto" src="${goto}"/>
```

But if I change the name "goto" to anything else, "got" for instance, then it woks fine !

I guess that this word is protected because used for another purpose, but I didn't find a clue about this problem on the net.

Does anyone know something about this matter ? I don't really need "goto" but I would like to know why I can't use it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[goto is a reserved word in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334376/goto-keyword-in-java), and as JSP's are translated into Java source code the variable name will appear somewhere in that code, causing the compilation issue.

Comment: Ok, I understand. I forgot that a JSP is no more than a servlet at the end,so it's perfectly normal that the "goto" keyword as a variable name would provoke an error. Thank you.